# How to validate ssl certificate on amazon ELB?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-elb, amazon-iam

I'm writing a script that loads IAM certificate to some ELB in order to check if it's valid.
When I tested it, I used an invalid private key on purpose to see if I could load it to the ELB.... and the problem - it gets loaded!
So my questions are-

1. How is this possible? I know for a fact that if you use AWS console you can't do something like that.
2. Is there a boto way to check if a cert is valid? (not using openssl, this is what I'm trying to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean when you say "check if it's valid"?  If you try to upload a malformed PEM file (the text of the cert isn't valid) then it will definitely throw an error since it can't decode the file. Also, if you try to upload a mismatched public & private key it will also throw an error.  I just tested these sorts of cases myself and got the following error:

> The private key did not match the public key provided. Please verify the key material and try again.

If you're referring to testing that a certificate is signed, authentic, and not expired, then the ELB isn't going to do any of that. According to the [AWS documentation for ELBs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html) it's perfectly fine to make use of self-signed certificates, and certs will also continue to work (whether CA signed or self-signed) even if expired.  Both self-signed certs and expired certs are "valid" as far as operation of a secure SSL connection goes.  Whether the cert is signed and unexpired or not is really just a means of providing authentication that it's a legitimate certificate.

If you are asking about testing if a certificate is properly signed and not expired then you would need to test for these sorts of things yourself, typically by leveraging something like openssl.

Comment: I mean malformed text. Like when I take the private key and add some string to the end of it. On boto it lets me load it to the ELB and on AWS console it sometimes does and sometimes doesn't. weird. Anyhow I'm only talking about CA signed certs (but thanks for the insight, didn't know that). Any idea?